# Issue with routes not calling the correct page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I always thought routes was straightforward but it clearly isn't. I want my page to show data.html.erb but it keeps on showing show.html.erb. These are my only two views in the user folder

My controller is:

```
 class UserController < ApplicationController

def data
  render :json =>  User.including_relationships
end

end
```

and my routes.rb is:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'users/:data' => 'users#data'
  resources :user
end
```

I always seem to get the show.html.erb page instead of the data.html.erb. Im sure there's something easy to fix here but what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The : before `data` in your route denotes a variable, try

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'users/data' => 'users#data'
  resources :user
end
```

Comment: Now it gives me the output of the json from the controller but it doesnt load the data.html.erb page???

Comment: Rendering the erb is default behavior, just omit the `render :json => ...` call in your controller method. If you want to access the data in the data.html.erb view, assign it to a variable in your controller method `@foo = User.including_relationships`.

Comment: I need the json as I'm trying to use it in the graphing library d3.js

Comment: You can call `.to_json` on the `@foo` variable in the view or store the JSON directly into the variable: `@foo = User.including_relationships.to_json`